# SED specification for USB sticks?

Tags: disk-encryption, hardware, usb-drive

As I got from my preliminary research, there is an established standard [TCG Opal 2.0](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/storage-work-group-storage-security-subsystem-class-opal/) which defines in specification the principles of SED encryption thus enabling the interoperability between vendors.

Upon reading the [specification](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG-Storage-Opal-SSC-v2p02-r1p0_pub24jan2022.pdf) my understanding was that it covers only block storage devices (LBA) and does **not** cover USB sticks.

If my understanding is correct next question does the similar industry standard exist for flash drives?

Reading [Opal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opal_Storage_Specification) and [FDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) wiki articles didn't bring any clarity into the topic.

On SE HardRec we have a [question about that](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/usb-memory-stick-with-automatic-encryption), but it didn't gather any responses since 2016.

Comment: Generally, hardware-based disk encryption is a disaster of implementation errors, so I would recommend against using it in general.

Comment: what are the other options besides SED? VeraCrypt containers?

Comment: If you don't need portability, use the default option on your OS (Bitlocker, FileVault, or LUKS).  If you do, VeraCrypt is typically fine.